# 'Could not update file ICEauthority file /home/user/.ICEauthority

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint

This is a Debian build of Linux Mint, but should be able to work on other versions of Linux. When I try to log in, it looks like I am able to enter the workspace, then it spits out an error of

```
Could not update file ICEauthority /home/user/.ICEauthority
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to fix this is: Boot up, and when you are prompted to log in, hit 
`Ctrl + Alt + F1`.

When the terminal opens, type your user name, then the password. 
You now should be in your account/user from the terminal. From there type:

```
sudo chown username:groupname /home
sudo chown username:groupname /home/username
sudo chown username:groupname /home/username/.ICEauthority
```

If you don't know your groupname, typically it is your username, but to check use `id -gn`. Once you have typed the three `sudo chown` commands correctly, hit on of these:

```
Ctrl + Alt + F7
Alt + F7
Ctrl + Alt + F8
```

This now should've moved you back to the main GUI log in page. Log in and you now should be able to access your account/user in GUI mode

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I found my problem;

```
sudo chown username:groupname /home/username/.ICEauthority
```

This is what I needed so I hope any other will find this and get it working.

I got this after I wanted to start into CLI by systemctl, but then I couldn't start GUI and hours went by searching, until now by using:
(not exactly correct but you get the idea)

`systemctl set-default.target multi-user.target`

and the above fixed it.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, the purpose is to provide answers to questions. Providing an answer that's "not exactly correct but..." isn't exactly very helpful. Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741619/edit) the question to complete it so that another, less experienced user who doesn't necessarily "get the idea" can attempt to resolve their issue by following your advice.